# How to get the iframe seamless effect with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

Whit the new html5 iframe attributes, it shows new options, like the `seamless` attribute, that is able to:

> An  that looks like it is a part of the containing document:

```
 <iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" seamless></iframe>
```

But no browser supports it yet. how can i get the same 'seamless' effect with css?

If not possible, i would appreciate it one could direct me to an alternative to the iframe tag. js, jquery?(php not an option for me right now)

- [HTML iframe seamless Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_seamless.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code in the past with great success / hope it comes in usefull

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="https://www.example.com" width="680" height="900" seamless></iframe>
```

Comment: `that looks like it is a part of the containing document:` - whit that line of code, it doesn't look like part of the document!